# Pie Chart without labels in JFreeChart

Tags: java, charts, apache-poi, jfreechart

I need to create a pie chart like this, but without the labels.

[image]

The mobile names like "Nokia Lumia" and "IPhone 5s" should not be shown in the chart; it's required only in the bottom part of explaining the legends.

I am using this with the help of [jfreechart](/questions/tagged/jfreechart) and apache [poi](/questions/tagged/poi) in Java.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: You can see examples in this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/pie-chart.htm)

Comment: I asked this doubt only for jfreechart plugin but the link you gave is for javaFX app @GAVD

Comment: You may wish to [review this meta post on "urgent" / "in a hurry" and questions here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6506/an-urgent-tag-for-questions-that-need-answers-within-minutes)

Comment: Start with this [example](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html) that's comes with [tag:jfreechart].

Comment: I have tried creating a chart..its not a problem. But i want to have a pie chart without labels. That's what i am struggling with. @Catalina Island

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed [`BarChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html) like this:

- Show legends.

  ```
  JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(
      "Smart Phones Manufactured / Q3 2011",  // chart title
      dataset,            // data
      true,               // legend <<<<<<<<<<
      true,               // tooltips
      false               // no URL generation
  );
  ```
- Don't show labels.

  ```
  // customise the section label appearance
  // plot.setLabelFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 20));
  // plot.setLabelLinkPaint(Color.WHITE);
  // plot.setLabelLinkStroke(new BasicStroke(2.0f));
  // plot.setLabelOutlineStroke(null);
  // plot.setLabelPaint(Color.WHITE);
  // plot.setLabelBackgroundPaint(null);
  plot.setLabelGenerator(null);
  ```

[image]